# gem install cannot find a header file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, header-files

Following along the github README for talib_ruby:

```
sudo port install ta-lib
```

Complete. Next is where the trouble begins.

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch PLATFORM" gem install talib_ruby -- --with-talib-include=ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_TALIB_HEADERS  --with-talib-lib=ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_TALIB_LIBS
```

This install fails I believe because apparently it cannot find the ta_abstract.h file

```
talib.c:2:25: error: ta_abstract.h: No such file or directory

.
.
.
many more errors
```

I have included in my .bash_profile file the following:

```
export ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_TALIB_HEADERS=/opt/local/var/macports/software/ta-lib/0.4.0_0/opt/local/include/ta-lib
export ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_TALIB_LIBS=/opt/local/var/macports/software/ta-lib/0.4.0_0/opt/local/lib
```

And indeed the ta_abstract.h file is located where I'm saying in the ABSOLUTE_PATH variable assignment.

What gives?

UPDATE:

When all else fails, email correspondence with the gem author may help. Instead of export ABSOLUTE_PATH, he suggests passing the actual path in with the install. Along with explicitly passing in ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64", which works for Snow Leopard. The install still fails but now because it has issues with the talib.c file and certain functions therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question was answered by the gem author via email, but I'd like to share the solution.

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install talib_ruby -- --with-talib-include=/opt/local/var/macports/software/ta-lib/0.4.0_0/opt/local/include/ta-lib  --with-talib-lib=/opt/local/var/macports/software/ta-lib/0.4.0_0/opt/local/lib
```

It is important to note that this gem is also not compatible with Ruby 1.9.2. From what the error list generated, it had some issues with the definition of struct RObject (fill in Object with String, Array, etc), which I traced to the ruby.h header file. If you'd like to use this gem, you can install rvm and then type

```
rvm install ruby-1.8.7 --with-readline-dir=/opt/local
```

From there, simply follow the guidance from the gem author with the input listed above.

UPDATE: the gem author has made talib_ruby compatible with 1.9.x so there is no longer a need to install 1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

Observe

`sudo echo $ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_TALIB_HEADERS`

`echo ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_TALIB_HEADERS`

```
have included in **my** .bash_profile file the following:
```

`sudo`

Are you root?

put the env vars on the command line and you should be good, alternatively add them to root's env.

Comment: I shall be attempting this feat shortly.

Comment: When I type the sudo echo $... into command line I get the correct path. But the gem install still cannot find the header file. I get the same results if I try to install from ~/home or from root. I cannot log in as su though, but I think that's an OSX thing and not a factor here, no?

Comment: $ echo $UID $USER
501 milktrader

Answer (score 0):

Just adding an answer for brew installed ta-lib.

> env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install talib_ruby -- --with-talib-include=/usr/local/include/ta-lib --with-talib-lib=/usr/local/lib