# gem install including referenced JAR fails

Tags: ruby, bash, jar, rubygems

I am trying to install the `ta-indicator` gem via `gem install ta-indicator` but the install keeps failing with the following error. What am I missing?

```
talib.c:2:32: fatal error: ta-lib/ta_abstract.h: No such file or directory
```

Thanks to other help on SO I figured out that I needed the ta-lb JAR on my path (shown below). The JAR is located in `~/Desktop/_REPOS/misc/stock_analysis/forex/oanda/ruby`:

```
king@DESKTOP-US7LR7D MINGW64 ~/Desktop/_REPOS/misc/stock_analysis/forex/oanda/ruby (master)
$ env
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=DESKTOP-US7LR7D
HOMEPATH=\Users\king
MANPATH=/mingw64/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/man:/share/man:
APPDATA=C:\Users\king\AppData\Roaming
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
HOSTNAME=DESKTOP-US7LR7D
SHELL=/usr/bin/bash
TERM=cygwin
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel
WINDIR=C:\Windows
TMPDIR=/tmp
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
USERDOMAIN=DESKTOP-US7LR7D
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
OS=Windows_NT
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
TEMP=/tmp
COMMONPROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files\Common Files
USERNAME=king
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
PATH=/c/Users/king/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/king/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cmd:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/king/Desktop/_REPOS/misc/stock_analysis/forex/oanda/ruby:/c/Ruby22-x64/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
EXEPATH=C:\Program Files\Git
PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PWD=/c/Users/king/Desktop/_REPOS/misc/stock_analysis/forex/oanda/ruby
SYSTEMDRIVE=C:
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\king
PS1=\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:${PWD//[^[:ascii:]]/?}\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$
LOGONSERVER=\\DESKTOP-US7LR7D
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\king\AppData\Local
!C:=C:\Users\king\Desktop\_REPOS\misc\stock_analysis\forex\oanda\ruby
SSH_ASKPASS=/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
SHLVL=1
HOME=/c/Users/king
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.RB;.RBW
PLINK_PROTOCOL=ssh
HOMEDRIVE=C:
PROMPT=$P$G
MSYSTEM=MINGW64
COMSPEC=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
TMP=/tmp
SYSTEMROOT=C:\Windows
PRINTER=Microsoft Print to PDF
PROCESSOR_REVISION=3d04
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw64/share/pkgconfig
ACLOCAL_PATH=/mingw64/share/aclocal:/usr/share/aclocal
INFOPATH=/usr/local/info:/usr/share/info:/usr/info:/share/info:
PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files
DISPLAY=needs-to-be-defined
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4
SESSIONNAME=Console
COMPUTERNAME=DESKTOP-US7LR7D
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Location of JAR:

```
king@DESKTOP-US7LR7D MINGW64 ~/Desktop/_REPOS/misc/stock_analysis/forex/oanda/ruby (master)
$ ls
getTimes.rb  indicators_test.rb  oanda_api.rb  ruby.algorithms.rb  ta-lib-0.4.0.jar
```

**Unique question because:**

I am using windows 10, and git-bash.exe to run the command (not linux)

Adding the fully specified path to the ruby gem install doesnt seem to be possible (likely because I dont know what I am doing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a cool technical analysis library.  anyway, it seems you are missing the C library development headers.  you can download that from the [TA-Lib site](http://ta-lib.org/hdr_dw.html).  The header files (.h) should probably be placed in the `/usr/include/ta-lib` directory.

this may be a duplicate of [gem install cannot find a header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618376/gem-install-cannot-find-a-header-file)

Comment: Arent the C library headers in the JAR file? All of the other downloads on that page seem to be for linux systems

Comment: Cygwin is very much like a Linux system and is mostly compatible with Linux source code. GCC will look for the header files in the `/usr/include/ta-lib` folder in both systems.