# Guide to installing ta-lib on Windows for Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, ta-lib

I have tried for quite a while to install ta-lib so I can use some of the indicator functions for trading based on [this](https://github.com/mlamby/indicator) github example. So far I have determined that I need to:

1. run `gem install talib_ruby`

   ```
   C:\Users\king\Desktop\_REPOS\misc\stock_analysis\forex\oanda\ruby>gem install talib_ruby
   Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
   ERROR:  Error installing talib_ruby:
       ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

   C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160810-7176-j5lye2.rb extconf.rb
   checking for TA_Initialize() in -lta_lib... no
   creating Makefile

   make "DESTDIR=" clean

   make "DESTDIR="
   generating talib-x64-mingw32.def
   compiling talib.c
   talib.c:2:32: fatal error: ta-lib/ta_abstract.h: No such file or directory
   compilation terminated.
   make: *** [talib.o] Error 1

   make failed, exit code 2
   ....
   ```
2. Download ta-lib header files which are in the msvc from [here](http://ta-lib.org/hdr_dw.html)
3. Tell the talib_ruby gem where the ta-lib files when installing. Based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618376/gem-install-cannot-find-a-header-file) the correct command should look something like: `sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install talib_ruby -- --with-talib-include=/opt/local/var/macports/software/ta-lib/0.4.0_0/opt/local/include/ta-lib  --with-talib-lib=/opt/local/var/macports/software/ta-lib/0.4.0_0/opt/local/lib`
   . The command specifies a path to a lib folder which is missing from the ta-lib I downloaded. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows?
Sorry for my english.
My system: Windows 7 SP1 x64, ruby 2.2.4p230

1. You have to install Ruby Development Kit to build the binary extensions.
2. Download and extract [source](http://ta-lib.org/hdr_dw.html), I used ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz.
3. Run `msys.bat` from Ruby DevKit or if you have installed mingw as part of [RubyInstaller](https://rubyinstaller.org/), run either `mingw64.exe` or `ming32.exe`. Navigate to ta-lib source files (in my case it is `/d/dev/ta-lib`) and build the library:

   ```
   cd /d/dev/ta-lib
   ./configure
   make
   ```
4. Because the path to C headers [hardcoded](https://github.com/rivella50/talib-ruby/blob/master/ext/talib/talib.c#L2) in gem to `#include <ta-lib/ta_abstract.h>`, I just make a new directory `ta-lib` within `d:\dev\ta-lib\include` source folder and all copy header files here. (Files in d:\dev\ta-lib\include*.h are copied to d:\dev\ta-lib\include\ta-lib)
5. Install gem. Exit the msys or mingw terminal and run the following in your Windows cmd. Be sure to replace these paths with the correct path to your ta-lib source:

   ```
   gem install talib_ruby -- --with-talib-include=d:/dev/ta-lib/include --with-talib-lib=d:/dev/ta-lib/src/.libs
   ```

   Make sure to change paths to yours.